# In Flutter I have a number of same async function running whoose result can come at any time. But I want to process the results sequentially

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I have a stream of text, I am converting them in paragraphs and sending it to eleven labs api to fetch audio.

My code :

```
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  ConcatenatingAudioSource _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
  String streamingText = '';
  String accumulatedText = '';

  final StreamController<String> _streamController = StreamController<String>();

  Future<UserModel?> _getUserData() async {
    return await ref.read(authProvider);
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAndPlay(String paragraph) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            'https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${widget.voiceId}/stream'),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'audio/mpeg',
          'xi-api-key': apiKeyElevenLabs,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: json.encode({
          "text": paragraph,
          "model_id": "eleven_monolingual_v1",
          "voice_settings": {"stability": .5, "similarity_boost": true}
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final bytes = response.bodyBytes;
        await _playlist.add(MyCustomSource(bytes));
        if (_playlist.length == 1) {
          _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(_playlist);
          _audioPlayer.play();
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load audio');
        return;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  void _fetchData(String userMessage) async {
    _audioPlayer.stop();
    _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
    setState(() {
      isSend = true;
    });
    final UserModel? user = await _getUserData();
    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers["x-api-key"] =
    "jhdfs979837r98327rtf09382reu9328r4fyh093u8";
    dio.options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    dio.options.headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked";
    dio.options.headers["X-Content-Type-Options"] = "nosniff";
    String url =
        dotenv.env['APIURL'];
    Map<String, dynamic> requestData = {
      "authProvider": "es",
      "authToken": user!.accessToken,
      "userID": user.userID,
      "guruUserID": widget.guruUserId,
      "guruID": widget.guruId,
      "prompt": userMessage,
    };

    Response<ResponseBody>? response;

    try {
      response = await dio.post(
        url,
        data: requestData,
        options: Options(
          responseType: ResponseType.stream,
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is DioException && e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
        await _refreshToken(user, _fetchData);
      } else {
        print("Error making API request: $e");
      }
    }

    Stream<Uint8List>? stream = response?.data?.stream;

    if (stream != null) {
      final controller = StreamController<String>();
      int initialIndex = messages.length;

      String accumulatedParagraphs = '';

      stream.listen((data) {
        final chunkData = utf8.decode(data);
        accumulatedText += chunkData;
        int paragraphEndIndex = accumulatedText.indexOf("\n\n");
        while (paragraphEndIndex != -1) {
          final paragraph = accumulatedText.substring(0, paragraphEndIndex);
          _fetchAndPlay(paragraph);
          accumulatedParagraphs += '$paragraph\n\n';
          accumulatedText = accumulatedText.substring(paragraphEndIndex + 2);
          paragraphEndIndex = accumulatedText.indexOf("\n\n");

          if (accumulatedParagraphs.isNotEmpty) {
            if (messages.length > initialIndex) {
              messages.removeAt(0);
            }
            messages = [accumulatedParagraphs, ...messages];
            controller.add(accumulatedParagraphs);
            _streamController.add(accumulatedParagraphs);
            accumulatedText = '';
          }
        }
      }, onDone: () {
        if (accumulatedText.isNotEmpty) {
          String lastPara = accumulatedText;
          accumulatedParagraphs += lastPara;
          if (messages.length > initialIndex) {
            messages.removeAt(0);
          }
          messages = [accumulatedParagraphs, ...messages];
          controller.add(accumulatedParagraphs);
          _streamController.add(accumulatedParagraphs);
          _fetchAndPlay(lastPara);
          accumulatedText = '';
          setState(() {
            isSend = false;
          });
        }
        controller.close();
      });
    }
  }
```

Now whats happening is that if second paragraph is much smaller than first, it will get processed first and start playing before first paragraph. But I want them to play in sequence. Also I don't want to wait till I have all the paragraphs, I want to start the audio the moment I get the first paragraph.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: check the `Stream` API - for example: `stream.transform(utf8.decoder). transform(LineSplitter()).asyncMap(playParagraph).drain()` - here `playParagraph` is your methods that takes a single `String` as a parameter and plays it

Comment: But then it will play one paragraph and then stop and wait for another paragraph. So there will be quite a delay between the two. I want the playback to be continuous.

Comment: so why to divide it into paragraphs at all?

Comment: So I can start audio as soon as possible. Rather than sending the whole text to eleven labs and then waiting for entire text to get converted. I send them paragraph by paragraph, so the audio will start much faster

So far example if text is large if I send them at once, it can take two minutes to start playing audio but if I send the first paragraph the moment it generated, audio will start in seconds

Comment: Then divide it into N paragraphs and call 11labs API N times - it will create N `Future` objects you can pass to `Future.wait` static method, also call `then` method for the first `Future` to play the first paragraph as it gets the response

Comment: But I don't know how many paragraphs I will recieve beforehand.

But may be can't I use something like Future.wait to each request? But How?

Comment: But I don't have big string. Its coming in stream. I am dividing it in paragraph by identifying "\n\n" in the stream

Comment: So you have to forget everything I wrote and proceed as I wrote in my first comment: you cannot call the API if you don't have a string (paragraph) so you have to wait until you get it from the stream

Comment: But that won't work. As I explained in my reply. This is not what I want. I am looking into something like Queue or similar right now but failing in implementation

Comment: I don't understand one thing: you are using `onDone` so it means your stream is not an endless stream of data, if so it seems that you know how many paragraphs you have, don't you?

Comment: I can't know it beforehand. Only when it comes to OnDone, I can be sure of how many paragraphs it has. The responses are basically coming from ChatGpt. It can be a short response or large response. I don't know beforehand how large with. how many paragraphs the response will have. But I want to start the playback the moment a single paragraph is complete rather than waiting for entire response to finish.

I can do this on web successfully with react but facing issues on Flutter

Comment: and have you measured what is the time difference between the first byte received and onDone called? I am pretty sure it's a fraction of second...

Comment: Its not really.  I can have a response wiith 7-8 paragraphs and the delay seems noticable

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list of completers to unlock sequentially the calls, here is some really high level code:

```
  final completers = List.generate(paragraphs.length, (index) => Completer<YourAudio>());

  void reproduceAudio(){
    unawaited(fetchAllParagraphs());
    for(var completer in completers){
      final paragraphAudio = await completer.future;
      /// reproduce;
    }
  }

  void fetchAllParagraphs() async {
   await Future.wait(
      List.generate(
        paragraph.length,
        (index) async {
          final audio = api.fetch(paragraph[index]);
          completers[index].complete(audio);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

So, what you do is:

- Fetch in paralel all audios
- Complete the indexed completer with the audio whenever it arrives
- Play sequentially the content of the completers

Please be careful to add some error handling, if one future gets stuck this whole thing gets stuck :)

Comment: The thing is I don't know paragraphs length beforehand. If I did I could just run them in a for loop and await for each item. I am generating paragraphs from the stream of text.

Comment: Then you should use a stream which emits a list of audios:
```{
var counter = 0;
/// listen stream
/// when the stream has a length of counter + 1 then check the value at index counter
/// If the value is not null then reproduce it, otherwise skip

}```